# QGIS - How to pin each attribute form to a fixed position while digitizing features

Tags: qgis, digitizing

When I'm digitizing data every attribute form pops up in a different place (appears to be incrementally changed coordinates on the screen). This means that when digitising a series of features the attribute form slowly 'wanders' down and then off the screen! Not very useful as I need to add attributes on the form (either auto-generated form or drag-and-drop design).

This behaviour is not supposed to happen as far as I can see:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6611

But it does on my installation (currently 3.28.3) and I wonder if there is a setting somewhere that switches off this behaviour.

When I manually re-locate the form, the next form opens in a relative position to that one, so there is obviously something being calculated somewhere - I just can't find the setting if it exists.

Other similar questions don't seem to have been answered and I don't think this is a bug (hence asking here rather than reporting it directly)

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: There is a quirk here - if I allow the form to fully disappear (i.e. keep adding new features but don't relocate the form each time), the next form is placed part way up the screen, and the pattern repeats... which suggests there is a deliberate process going on inside QGIS...

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary solution, check `Suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation` in 'Settings -> Options -> Digitizing'.

Then, open Attribute Table and set 'Show Edited and New Features'

[image]

And use the attribute table to add attribute values for newly added feature.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is useful (I acknowledge you marked it as temporary), but uses it screen footprint- the attribute table disappears behind the canvas when the canvas has focus (digitise a new feature) so I need to dock the table (as I think you have done). However with an attribute form with more than 2 or 3 fields to complete, this becomes ineffective. Also, with an attribute form the first field is the focus so you can cycle through rather than lots of mouse action... Appreciate the thoughts but I'm not calling it the solution :-)